# Apache beam: WriteToText or WriteToFiles

Tags: python, apache-beam

I found it a little confusing when writing result to files with apache beam.

It seems to me that [WriteToText](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.23.0/_modules/apache_beam/io/textio.html#WriteToText) and [WriteToFiles](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.23.0/_modules/apache_beam/io/fileio.html#EmptyMatchTreatment) do the same thing.

I can define num of shards, destination file path, custom sink...

What is the difference and when to use which?